# FontAwesome icons smoothing in Firefox

Tags: css

can anyone please help me with making Firefox smooth FA icons. -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; doesnt work. Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7fVA.png)

Comment: try this.

Also not working* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```